# How to view a db file with sqlitebrowser

Tags: android, sqlite

Recently I want to view a db file with help of a tool. I **don't have access** to the source code, but after Googling, I found [sqlitebrowser](https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser/) may be useful for me. I succeeded in opening db file with it.

My way is:

- extract file from android

  > adb exec-out run-as package.name cat databases/file > file
- open the file manually with `sqlitebrowser`

However it's very troublesome. So I want to write a script to wrap the above two steps. But I do not have any idea how to do it.

**Please note I don't want to modify my project**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution:

> adb exec-out run-as package.name cat databases/file > file
>
> /Applications/DB\ Browser\ for\ SQLite.app/Contents/MacOS/DB\ Browser\ for\ SQLite file

The most important is : `sqlitebrowser file`.We can input file directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to debug content of your database you may consider [stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/). I really like those features and it's easy to use.

Answer (score -1):

[This](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Android-Debug-Database) nifty library **opens sqlite database in your computers web browser**,when your app is running. Setup with your project should be straightforward.

Comment: I just want to view a db file and it has nothing to do with application project.

Comment: Ah sorry! Sqlite browser is the best option you got then.

Comment: You never mentioed you didn't have access to source code. Please edit your question